# Why do so few people use the $\equiv$ symbol for identities?

Tags: notation

I've always been taught to write, for example, $$\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2\theta \color{red}{\equiv} 1,$$ rather than $$\sin^2(\theta)+\cos^2\theta \color{red}{=} 1,$$ and $$x(x+2)\color{red}{\equiv} x^2+2x$$ rather than $$x(x+2)\color{red}{=}x^2+2x, $$as $\equiv$ denotes an identity, so the equation is true for **all** values of the variable(s), whereas $=$ is an equation that only holds for some **specific** values of the variable.

I've happily taken this on board, but I've seen so few people write it.

In this context only (i.e. with regards to identities), are $=$ and $\equiv$ interchangeable, or have I been lied to/deceived?

Are both correct in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: Because, in most of the cases it doesn't cause any confusion.

Comment: I was never taught $\equiv$ for identities. I've always considered identities to be bona fide equalities of functions or elements of polynomial / power series rings etc. or at least logical $\forall$ statements with the symbols suppressed for efficiency.

Comment: The person who taught you is more careful than many of us are. One usually lets context determine the meaning of $=$.

Comment: I've only ever seen $\equiv$ used when defining a new quantity.

Comment: I guess one could define $\varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\equiv\psi(x_1, \ldots ,x_n)$ as bounding $x_1, \ldots ,x_n$ universally, that is,as $\forall x_1, \ldots x_n(\varphi(x_1, \ldots, x_n)\equiv\psi(x_1, \ldots ,x_n))$. The reasons why I don't use it are that I don't think the notation is common enough and it's not a problem at all for me to write the quantifiers.

Comment: The problem is, for example, if I'm doing a mechanics problem and there are lots of trig. functions, and I'm trying to find the values of $\theta$, say, for which $f(\theta)=0$ (where $f$ is some complicated function of $\theta$), only to find out that it should be an identity, and it's, in fact, true for all $\theta$, so I spend 20-odd minutes deducing that $0=0.$ Is there a way I could avoid this and immediately identify whether the context means $\equiv$ rather than $=$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\equiv$ symbol indeed is used when the values are identical, independent of the variable. For example, if $f(x) = 0 \quad \forall x$, then we write $f \equiv 0$. Write $x(x+2) \equiv x²+2x$ is correct also, because it is true for all x. However, people really don't give it so much importance, it serves just as a reminder.